# SVN/Tortoise SVN - can connect to repository, but not add folders/files

Tags: svn, tortoise-svn

I have SVN set up and running on a remote server (svn.mydomain.com/svn) and I can browse the repository from my local machine using repo-browser against svn://svn.mydomain.com/svn, but when I try to create a new directory or add a new file I get an "Authorization Failed!" message.

I am never asked to input my credentials, and while I have a user/pass set up on the server in the passwd file, I don't ever get a chance to supply this information via TortoiseSVN.

I've tried the trick of going into TortoiseSVN Settings/Saved Data/Authentication Data to clear the cache, but that button is grayed out, because I have no stored authentication data to delete. So why isn't TortoiseSVN prompting me to supply credentials, instead of just throwing up an "Authorization Failed!" message?

This also happens when I log onto the remote machine, browse with the repo-browser, and try to create a new folder.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably only read permission on the remote server. Try to get write access. If it is a good linux system, the svn server has good acl files with them it can be set. It is not clientdide problem.

Although some help were, if you played a little bit with the command line svn tool, it could give a better info about what exactly doesn't go, but it 99% that your write permission isn't set on the server side.

Comment: Not sure how I would check the permissions. This is a Windows server, though, not Linux. What command lines would help me verify the permission settings?

Comment: No-no, your problem is not with the filesystem permission, but your subversion server handles its repositories by default as readonly. You need to say them explicitly, which user, to which repository, which permission has.

Comment: That's in the svnserve and passwd files, right? I have the "auth" permissions in the svnserve file set to "write," and I have a user/pwd set up in the passwd file, but like I said, I'm not ever being challenged to enter the user/pwd credentials.

Comment: This is ok, but not all. There are repository-specific access control lists, too.